# How do i receive and use a string into template of a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-1.6

I'm starting to work with directives and right now i'm trying to render buttons using permission levels.

Let's say i want to render this button

```
<a ui-sref="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCadastro"><div id="addButton" class="btn btn-success">Add</div></a>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('test', function($http){
$http.get('system/test/gettemplate')
.then(function(response){
    if(response.data.success){ // small verification to know if it worked and i got a string with the template
        $scope.template = response.data.template;
    }
})
return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{},
    template: $scope.template // which is my template that comes from back-end
}
})
```

I know I'm missing something pretty small, but I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 2):

You should return your template in the `.then` of your `$http` call. It is an **asynchronous** call, so when tried to `return { ... }`, `$scope.template` may not have been set yet.

```
.directive('test', function($http) {
    $http.get('system/test/gettemplate').then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.success) {
            $scope.template = response.data.template;
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope:{},
                template: $scope.template
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i've tried something like this, but i keep getting a https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20testDirective

Comment: @LaTreta You have a problem in your dependency injection. It seems you missed to inject something ($scope maybe).

Comment: it's not that case. I've added the needed.